# XMPP Smack - how to check if connection is active or broken?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am using the Smack library to add XMPP support to my android app. The problem I face is that if there is  momentary disruption in net, the network state does not change and the XMPPConnection object returns true for isConnected() and isAuthenticated() even though it is broken. What method can I invoke which will attempt a server call and upon failing, let me know that the connection is broken?

Appreciate your help in fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `PingManager.pingMyServer()`

Comment: Thank you, let me try that.